# Error when using # symbol with Dreamweaver and CommonSpot libraries

Tags: coldfusion, dreamweaver, commonspot

Does anyone know how to manage libraries in Dreamweaver for CommonSpot?  (I'm very new to CommonSpot).

CommonSpot is returning an error wherever I use `#` symbol. Somehow I managed to remove all of the `#` symbols from the libraries. But I want to create libraries in Dreamweaver which defines a library as starting with:

```
<!-- #BeginLibraryItem ...
```

This causes a problem because of the `#` symbol.

Does CommonSpot have anything like library? Or are there any escape characters I can use to achieve this?

Comment: I am not familiar with either of those, but in ColdFusion literal `#` characters must be escaped by using two symbols `##`. If that does not help, please post the error message.

Comment: yeah, I have managed the # symbol by replacing it with "##", but I was unable to use it when creating libraries, the library name does start contain # symbol.

I have tried to keep ## in library name, but it is taking as a comment! not as a library

Comment: Sorry, I do not use either one. So that was my best shot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CF must be evaluating the comment. Here are a couple ideas.

- Check if there is a cfoutput tag around the entire file. If so, adjust them to not be around the comment

If currently this

```
<cfoutput>
...
<!-- #BeginLibraryItem ... -->
...
</cfoutput>
```

try this

```
<cfoutput>
...
</cfoutput>
<!-- #BeginLibraryItem... -->
<cfoutput>
...
</cfoutput>
```

- Another option that might work depending on exactly how the library comments are evaluated is to make them CFML comments with 3 dashes instead of 2 to have the # ignored

like so...

```
<!--- #BeginLibraryItem ... --->
```

Comment: what ended up being the solution?